# Identifying Functional Dependencies

Tags: database, database-design, schema, database-normalization

I have the following schema in [first normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) (1NF) - that is all cells containing atomic values:

```
ClientRental (clientNo, propertyNo, clientName, propertyAddress, rent,
              rentStart, rentFinish, ownerNo, ownerName)
```

The general outline is that clients can rent many properties from a letting agents. Each property has one owner. For those of you familiar with the book, it is an example extracted from *Database Systems* by Connolly & Begg.

I am trying to identify the functional dependencies → candidate keys, partial dependencies and transitive dependencies, etc.

I am following a textbook, but their suggestions are somewhat poorly explained. Are my suggestions correct or not?

```
FD1 -> clientNo -> clientName
FD2 -> propertyNo -> propertyAddress, rent, ownerNo, ownerName
FD3 -> ownerNo -> ownerName
```

There are definitely more functional dependencies that I have missed, but my lack of experience is preventing me from identifying them. Obviously, I cannot determine the partial dependencies, because I haven't yet allocated a primary key for the above relation/schema.

How can I identify the other functional dependencies? I am not clear what determines something as a transitive dependency either...

My [3NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form) relations:

```
Client {clientNo(PK), clientName}
Owner {ownerNo(PK), ownerName}
Property {propertyNo (PK), propertyAddress, rent}
ClientRental {clientNo(PK), propertyNo(PK), rentStart, rentFinish, ownerNo(FK)}
```

Comment: A relation in 1NF still has to have a key. What's the key for ClientRental?

Comment: The key is clientNo & propertyNo

Comment: It doesn't really make sense for ownerNo to be an attribute of ClientRental. The key to that table is {clientNo, propertyNo}. Informally, that means that who the owner is depends in part on who rents the place. That's certainly not true. The owner is the same no matter who rents it. I'd expect ownerNo to be an attribute of Property instead.

Answer (score 5):

To improve to [2NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form), identify the non-key attributes that depend on only part of a candidate key, not on all of it. Start by determining whether any of the attributes in the set {clientName, propertyAddress, rent, rentStart, rentFinish, ownerNo, ownerName} depend only on either clientNo or propertyNo.

Now, one of the problems you'll run into online is that functional dependencies are actually determined by values, not by column names. Without representative sample values, we have to guess a little. But probably

```
clientNo -> clientName
propertyNo -> propertyAddress, ownerNo, ownerName
```

So we can decompose ClientRental this way.

```
Relation "clients"         { (clientNo), clientName}
Relation "properties"      { (propertyNo), propertyAddress, ownerNo, ownerName}
Relation "ClientRental"    { (clientNo, propertyNo), rent, rentStart, rentFinish}
```

In the USA, it's not true that propertyNo -> rent. (Your FD2. Unless by *rent* you mean the asking price.) In the USA, the lease determines the rent, and legally the lease has to include the address and the tenant. (All the tenants, actually. But that's a different issue.)

Since "client" and "properties" have only one column in their candidate keys, they must be in 2NF. I think all three of these relations are in 2NF.

Can you handle improving to [3NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form) (removing transitive dependencies) on your own?

**Later . . .**

Yes, there's at least one transitive dependency here: propertyNo -> ownerNo -> ownerName. Remove that transitive dependency by introducing a relation of owners.

```
Relation "clients"         { (clientNo), clientName}
Relation "properties"      { (propertyNo), propertyAddress, ownerNo}
Relation "owners"          { (ownerNo), ownerName}
Relation "ClientRental"    { (clientNo, propertyNo), rent, rentStart, rentFinish}
```

The relations "clients", "properties", and "owners" are in 3NF. In the real world, properties are often owned by multiple people or businesses, and they're also often leased to multiple people or businesses. But that kind of issue doesn't have anything to do with normalization. (Until you decide to support that real-world situation, that is.)

Anything else?

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I have already devised the relations required for 3NF. By rent I mean the monthly rent - agreed on prior to rental. For ease of I sake, I assume this is predetermined.

Answer (score 2):

There are probably 4 relations that should be identified:

- Client
- Owner
- Property
- Rental

Then, given the attributes in the ClientRental, we can reason:

- Client: {clientNo} ⟶ {clientName}
- Owner: {ownerNo} ⟶ {ownerName}
- Property: {propertyNo} ⟶ {propertyAddress, ownerNo}
- Rental: {rentStart, propertyNo} ⟶ {clientNo, propertyNo, rentFinish, rent}

For a given property, the start date is unique, so the combination is can provide a key (determinant); you can also argue that rentFinish and propertyNo would provide a key.

The rent could probably be an attribute of both Property and Rental; in the former, it is the asking rent, in the latter, the rent obtained.  A more realistic asking rent might well vary by time of year - the property might be more valuable in the summer months than in the winter months.

For transitive dependencies, consider the original ClientRental relation.  The propertyNo identifies the ownerNo (and ownerName), so there is a transitive dependency lurking in there.

Comment: Ok so ownerNo -> ownerName is a transitive dependency because ownerNo and ownerName can be determined by propertyNo? Also it seems you attempt to identify the relations prior to identifying the dependencies, whereas this book I have says to use the functional dependencies to determine the require relations....?

Comment: @user559142: I would not do what the book prescribes, no.  I would generally identify the main relations before messing around with functional dependencies, etc.  However, if I came up with a design and then found that in some relation there was repetition or transitive dependency, then I'd refactor into the separate constituent relations.  I suppose I can assume that a naïve designer might come up with the design described, but it would have to be a very naïve designer.

Comment: ok great, thanks for the advice. Could you please confirm that I have the right understanding of transitive dependency?

Comment: @user559142: As to the transitive relationship, that is the tricky stuff...if you accept that {rentStart, propertyNo} is a candidate key of the composite ClientRental relation schema, then propertyNo determines the owner, but because it is not 'the key, the whole key, and nothing but the key' that determines the owner (the rentStart does not affect the owner - at least when there is no record of successive owners of a property, along with the dates when each owned the property).  There is, therefore, a transitive dependency, as well as a dependency on part of a key, which indicates non-BCNF.

Comment: What if I have clientNo & propertyNo as the primary key? Surely then as propertyNo -> pAddress, rent, ownerNo, ownerName then ownerNo -> ownerName is a transitive dependency right? Does that also mean that ownerNo and ownerName are partially dependent on the primary key too?

Comment: @user559412: which relation would {clientNo, propertyNo} be the primary key of? A client might rent the property twice, say for spring break and Labor Day in the USA, and then there is no way for the combination to be the primary key of a table about single rentals. The transitive dependency would be propertyNo⟶ownerName; it is transitive because propertyNo⟶ownerNo and ownerNo⟶ownerName as well as the direct functional dependency.